# JavaFX Events Using Local Variables

Tags: events, variables, javafx, local, final

I have a method that creates an ImageView, called createImageView(), which uses EventHanlders to call vaious events.  I would like to be able to use local variables in this method.  What I usually do is assign final variables to use within the handle(Event) method.

In the method described below, when I go to use final I get the following errors:

> The final local variable initY cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type
>   The final local variable initY cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type
>   The final local variable dragAnchor cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Of course, removing final gives me this message:

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable initX inside an inner class defined in a different method

So what do I have to do to make this method work?

```java
private ImageView createImageView() {
    double initX;
    double initY;
    Point2D dragAnchor;

    imgView.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler < MouseEvent > () {
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
            //when mouse is pressed, store initial position
            initX = imgView.getTranslateX();
            initY = imgView.getTranslateY();
            dragAnchor = new Point2D(me.getSceneX(), me.getSceneY());
            me.consume();
        }
    });

    imgView.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler < MouseEvent > () {
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
            double dragX = me.getSceneX() - dragAnchor.getX();
            double dragY = me.getSceneY() - dragAnchor.getY();

            double newXPosition = initX + dragX;
            double newYPosition = initY + dragY;
            imgView.setTranslateX(newXPosition);
            imgView.setTranslateY(newYPosition);
            me.consume();
        }
    });

    imgView.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler < MouseEvent > () {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            imgView.setEffect(new Glow(0.5));
            event.consume();
        }
    });

    imgView.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler < MouseEvent > () {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            imgView.setEffect(new Glow(0.0));
            event.consume();
        }
    });
    return imgView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaFX properties instead of primitive types.

For example:

```
final DoubleProperty initX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
final ObjectProperty<Point2D> dragAnchor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
...
// in event handler
initX.set(
  imageView.getTranslateX()
);
dragAnchor.set(
  new Point2D(
    me.getSceneX(), 
    me.getSceneY()
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks jewelsea.  This works great for doubles, but the dragAnchor still gives me the same problem.  No biggie, my solution below seems to be working for now.

Comment: Updated example to show how you can use an `ObjectProperty` for the `dragAnchor`.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the 3 local variables and made them class variables and it worked.  If anyone doesn't mind offering a quick explanation as of why I would appreciate it.